# Загрузка значений в GetDriveType и GetVolumeInformatio из файла

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Как можно загрузить значения **'c:/'** диска в **GetDriveType и GetVolumeInformatio** из текстового файла, из первой строки текстового файла.

```
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  SerialNum,dtyp:Dword;
  a,b:DWORD;
  Buffer,disk: array [0..255] of char;
begin
dtyp:=GetDriveType('c:/'); // ВОТ ТУТ ЧТО БЫ МОЖНО БЫЛО ЗАГРУЗИТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 'c:/' ИЗ ФАЙЛА
  dtyp := DRIVE_REMOVABLE;
  GetVolumeInformation('c:/', Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), @SerialNum, a, b, nil, 0); // ВОТ ТУТ ЧТО БЫ МОЖНО БЫЛО ЗАГРУЗИТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 'c:/' ИЗ ФАЙЛА
  Edit1.text := IntToStr(SerialNum);
end;
```

Comment: Открыть и прочитать файл в буфер, адрес которого потом передать в `GetDriveType()`. Для чтения удобно использовать функции `_lopen()` и `_lread()` из kernel32.dll - у них всего 2 аргумента, а у `CreateFile()` аж 7.

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи:

```
Var
  s: TStringList;
  SerialNum,dtyp:Dword;
  a,b:DWORD;
  Buffer,disk: array [0..255] of char;
begin
s:=TStringList.Create;
s.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'file.txt');
dtyp:=GetDriveType(PChar(s[0]));
dtyp := DRIVE_REMOVABLE;
GetVolumeInformation(PChar(s[0]),Buffer,sizeof(Buffer),@SerialNum,a,b,nil,0);
edit1.text:=IntToStr(SerialNum);
s.Free;
end;
```